# install4j preserve layout permissions

Tags: linux, install4j

Is there any way to preserve the file permissions which are already set in the layout? I know I can set default permissions for folders and files in the installer but this applies globally, and is not what I'm looking for.

I want to have specific files have specific permissions.

Comment: Currently this is not possible with install4j.

Comment: @IngoKegel, thank you! I'll just write a script that first saves a "permission list" of the files in the layout and then one that runs at the end of the installer and chmod's each file to the specific permission.